# web-mode disable auto pairing mode does not work

Tags: web-mode, electric-pair-mode

I am having little issues with web-mode.

I am trying to disable the pairing which is done automatically when I try to insert double curly braces like this:

`{{<CURSOR>}}` , and hit space to start typing my code , it becomes `{{ }}}}`

here is what I did to try to disable it , but none of this works which is little frustrating.

```
(electric-pair-mode 1) ;; this is doing all the pairing for me.

(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  ;; none of these disabled it 
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-expanding -1)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing -1)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing -1)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing -1)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-quoting -1)

  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
  (setq web-mode-engines-alist '(("django" . "/templates/.*\\.html\\'"))))
```

I am `electric-pair-mode` for pairing and `use-package` for configuration.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior you describe.  Does this occur when loading only those two packages?

Comment: did you set the engine ? go `M-x web-mode-set-engine` then chose `django`, with the settings above , you should be able to reproduce it because this is the default behavior of web-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In elisp `nil` represents a false value.  Try:

```
(setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing nil)
(setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing nil)
```

`-1` is non-nil (see: `(if -1 "true!" "false!")`).

Comment: `true!`,  thanks for the heads up, i have `(tool-bar-mode -1)` , so I thought it will do the same thing for web-mode variable `-1`  will disable it as well.

Comment: this is so confusing , doing `c-h v` `tool-bar-mode` says it is value is `nil` that is why I set those values to `-1`.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe part of your init isn't getting evaluated so that command is getting ignored?

Comment: that might be the case , nonetheless , I am happy that `nil` disabled the auto-pairing and I am happy that I didn't have to debug the code evaluation path to figure out whats going on lol.